# If $f_k \not\to 0$ a.e., does there exist a subsequence, a set of positive measure, and $c > 0$, on which $\liminf |f_{k_j}| > c$?

Tags: measure-theory

Here you are another question in basic measure theory...

Let $f_k$ be a measurable sequence of functions on $(X,M,\mu)$ measure space. Suppose that $f_k$ *does not go to 0 a.e*.. Can I then find a set $A\subseteq X$ with positive measure and a subsequence $f_{k_j}$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\liminf_j |f_{k_j}(x)| > \varepsilon$ foreach $x\in A$?

Comment: Your measure theory textbook surely has a discussion of this.  Perhaps called "convergence in measure".  The "no" answer below shows that convergence in measure does not imply a.e. convergence.  This same example is probably in your textbook.


Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that convergence in measure does not imply a.e. convergence (I use Folland's Real Analysis, and there there is a good section on convergence in measure), but my question was more about the inverse, I think. 

Comment: Convergence a.e. does not imply convergence in measure. Consider f_{n} defined as f_{n}(x)=1 x>n and f_{n}(x)=0 x<=n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not true. For example, in $(0,1)$ take

$f_1 =1$,

$f_2=1_{(0,1/2)}$, $f_3= 1_{(1/2,1)}$

$f_4=1_{(0,1/3)}$, $f_5= 1_{(1/3,2/3)}$, $f_6= 1_{(2/3,1)}$

and so on. $f_k(x)$ does not go to 0 a.e. (the limit does not exist, for each x), but we can't find any succession that satisfies the statement, because $m(supp f_k)$ goes to zero